# Для каждой строки напечатать номера столбцов, которые имеют отрицательные элементы

Tags: c++, массивы

Задание - в названии темы.
Есть код, который нужно переделать.

Помогите пожалуйста, если сможете.

```
#include <conio.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <stdlib.h>
// Для каждой строки напечатать номера столбцов, которые имеют отрицательные элементы
using namespace std;
int main() { 
    int A[4][7]; 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int sum = 0, n; 
    printf("Выберите метод заполнения массива: \n"); 
    printf("1 - вручную: "); 
    printf("2 - рандом:  "); 
    printf("3 - рандом: "); 
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    printf("Полученный вид матрицы 4*7:\n"); 
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { 
        if (n == 2){ 
            A[i][j] = i + j; 
            printf(" %d", A[i][j]); 
        } 
        else if(n == 3){ 
            A[i][j] = rand() % -10 - 5; 
            printf(" %d",A[i][j]); 
        } 
        else{ 
            printf("A[%d][%d] = ", j, i); 
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]); 
        } 
        } 
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { 
        for (int j = 0; j< 7; ++j) { 
            if (A[i][j] < 0) 
            sum = sum + A[i][j]; 
        } 
        printf("Сумма элементов в столбце |%d| равна %d.\n", i+1,sum); 
        sum = 0; 
    } 
    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, доделал)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Для каждой строки напечатать номера столбцов, которые имеют отрицательные элементы
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int A[4][7];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int sum = 0, n;
    cout << "Выберите метод заполнения массива: \n";
    cout << "1 - вручную: ";
    cout << "2 - рандом:  ";
    cout << "3 - рандом: ";
    cin >> n;
    printf("Полученный вид матрицы 4*7:\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (n == 2){
            A[i][j] = i + j;
            printf(" %d", A[i][j]);
        }
        else if(n == 3){
            A[i][j] = rand() % -10 - 5;
            printf(" %d",A[i][j]);
        }
        else{
            printf("A[%d][%d] = ", j, i);
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
        }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j< 7; ++j) {
            if (A[i][j] < 0)
            sum = sum + A[i][j];
        }
        printf("Сумма отрицательных элементов в столбце |%d| равна %d.\n", i+1,sum);
        sum = 0;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j) {
        printf("В строке |%d| отрицательные эелементы имеют следующие столбцы: ", j+1);
        for (int i = 0; i< 4; ++i) {
            if (A[i][j] < 0)
            printf("%d ", i+1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Все работает, отлично.
Спасибо!

Comment: @Hinc, всегда пожалуйста)